# Expo Router is stopping my launching my app -- Error: Unable to resolve module ./node_modules/expo-router/entry from /path/to/source

Tags: expo, eas, expo-router

This happened a couple of days ago and it magically fixed itself after several hours.

It happened again today after I restarted my Mac whilst the simulator was running.

Basically I can build my project but whenever I connect to it I get this error and am unable to launch my app

```
None of these files exist:
  * node_modules/expo-router/entry(.native|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.ios.json|.native.json|.json|.ios.cjs|.native.cjs|.cjs|.ios.scss|.native.scss|.scss|.ios.sass|.native.sass|.sass|.ios.css|.native.css|.css|.ios.mjs|.native.mjs|.mjs)
  * node_modules/expo-router/entry/index(.native|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.ios.json|.native.json|.json|.ios.cjs|.native.cjs|.cjs|.ios.scss|.native.scss|.scss|.ios.sass|.native.sass|.sass|.ios.css|.native.css|.css|.ios.mjs|.native.mjs|.mjs)
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (/Users/***/Sites/***/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ModuleResolution.js:114:15)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (/Users/****/Sites/***/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js:277:43)
    at /Users/****/Sites/***/node_modules/metro/src/lib/transformHelpers.js:169:21
    at Server._resolveRelativePath (/Users/***/Sites/***/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:1045:12)
    at async Server.requestProcessor [as _processBundleRequest] (/Users/***/Sites/***/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:449:37)
    at async Server._processRequest (/Users/***/Sites/***/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:383:7)
```

---

My App.json

---

```
{
  "expo": {
    "scheme": "***",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "automatic",
    "splash": {
      "backgroundColor": "#ddffe2",
      "image": "./assets/icon.jpg",
      "resizeMode": "contain"
    },
    "icon": "./assets/icon.jpg",
    "name": "***",
    "slug": "***",
    "assetBundlePatterns" : [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "web": {
      "bundler": "metro"
    },
    "plugins": [
      [
        "expo-image-picker",
        {
          "photosPermission": "The app accesses your photos to let you share them with your friends."
        }
      ],
      "@react-native-firebase/app",
      [
        "expo-build-properties",
        {
          "ios": {
            "useFrameworks": "static",
            "deploymentTarget": "13.0"
          }
        }
      ]
    ],
    "ios": {
      "bundleIdentifier": "app.***.***",
      "googleServicesFile": "./GoogleService-Info.plist",
      "runtimeVersion": {
        "policy": "appVersion"
      }
    },
    "android": {
      "permissions": [
        "android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"
      ],
      "package": "app.***.***",
      "googleServicesFile": "./google-services.json",
      "runtimeVersion": "1.0.0"
    },
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "****"
      }
    },
    "updates": {
      "url": "https://u.expo.dev/*****"
    }
  },
  "web": {
    "bundler": "metro"
  }
}
```

---

My Package.json

```
{
  "name": "***",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "expo-router/entry",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo run:web",
    "upgrade:tamagui": "$npm_execpath up '*tamagui*' '@tamagui/*'",
    "predeploy": "expo export -p web",
    "deploy-hosting": "npm run predeploy && firebase deploy --only hosting:***",
    "storybook-generate": "sb-rn-get-stories",
    "storybook-watch": "sb-rn-watcher",
    "test": "node --experimental-vm-modules node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js"
  },
  "jest": {
    "extensionsToTreatAsEsm": [
      ".ts"
    ],
    "globals": {
      "__DEV__": true
    },
    "projects": [
      {
        "displayName": "web",
        "preset": "jest-expo/web",
        "testEnvironment": "jsdom",
        "testMatch": [
          "**/__tests__/web/**/*.tsx"
        ],
        "moduleFileExtensions": [
          "web.tsx",
          "web.js",
          "ts",
          "tsx",
          "js",
          "jsx",
          "json",
          "node"
        ],
        "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
          "./jest.setup.web.ts"
        ]
      },
      {
        "displayName": "native",
        "preset": "jest-expo",
        "testEnvironment": "jest-environment-node",
        "testMatch": [
          "**/__tests__/native/**/*.tsx"
        ],
        "moduleFileExtensions": [
          "ts",
          "tsx",
          "js",
          "jsx",
          "json",
          "node"
        ],
        "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
          "./jest.setup.ts"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!((jest-)?react-native|@react-native(-community)?)|expo(nent)?|@expo(nent)?/.*|@expo-google-fonts/.*|react-navigation|@react-navigation/.*|@unimodules/.*|unimodules|sentry-expo|native-base|react-native-svg)"
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo-google-fonts/nunito-sans": "^0.2.3",
    "@expo/config-plugins": "~7.2.2",
    "@expo/webpack-config": "^19.0.0",
    "@ptomasroos/react-native-multi-slider": "^2.2.2",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^19.0.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^19.0.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/crashlytics": "^19.0.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^19.0.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/storage": "^19.0.0",
    "@react-native-google-signin/google-signin": "^10.1.1",
    "@tamagui/animations-react-native": "^1.61.3",
    "@tamagui/babel-plugin": "^1.61.3",
    "@tamagui/config": "^1.61.3",
    "@tamagui/font-inter": "^1.61.3",
    "@tamagui/lucide-icons": "^1.61.3",
    "@tamagui/themes": "^1.61.3",
    "@types/firebase": "^3.2.1",
    "expo": "49.0.9",
    "expo-build-properties": "~0.8.3",
    "expo-constants": "~14.4.2",
    "expo-dev-client": "~2.4.13",
    "expo-font": "~11.4.0",
    "expo-image-picker": "~14.3.2",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~12.3.0",
    "expo-linking": "~5.0.2",
    "expo-router": "2.0.5",
    "expo-secure-store": "~12.3.1",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.20.5",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "expo-updates": "~0.18.19",
    "firebase": "^10.8.1",
    "jest-expo": "~49.0.0",
    "punycode": "^2.3.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.10",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.12.0",
    "react-native-google-places-autocomplete": "^2.5.6",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^17.1.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.3.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.22.0",
    "react-native-svg": "13.9.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^10.0.3",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.6",
    "tamagui": "^1.61.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.19.3",
    "@google/semantic-release-replace-plugin": "1.1.0",
    "@manypkg/cli": "^0.20.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.18.2",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "7.2.0",
    "@react-native-community/slider": "4.4.2",
    "@semantic-release/changelog": "6.0.1",
    "@semantic-release/git": "10.0.1",
    "@semantic-release/github": "8.0.6",
    "@semantic-release/npm": "9.0.1",
    "@semantic-release/release-notes-generator": "10.0.3",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.5.16",
    "@storybook/addon-controls": "^6.5.16",
    "@storybook/addon-ondevice-actions": "^6.5.7",
    "@storybook/addon-ondevice-controls": "^6.5.7",
    "@storybook/react-native": "^6.5.7",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^6.4.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-native": "^5.4.3",
    "@testing-library/react": "^14.2.1",
    "@testing-library/react-native": "^12.4.3",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.12",
    "@types/react": "~18.2.14",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.49.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.49.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.3.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-inline-environment-variables": "^0.4.4",
    "conventional-changelog-conventionalcommits": "5.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.21.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.32.1",
    "eslint-plugin-simple-import-sort": "^10.0.0",
    "firebase-mock": "^2.3.2",
    "jest": "^29.7.0",
    "prettier": "^2.8.3",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.6.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "^18.2.0",
    "semantic-release": "19.0.5",
    "typescript": "^5.1.3"
  },
  "volta": {
    "node": "18.17.0",
    "yarn": "3.6.1"
  },
  "private": true,
  "eslintConfig": {
    "env": {
      "jest": true
    }
  }
}
```

---

eas.json

```
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 7.3.0"
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal",
      "channel": "development"
    },
    "development-simulator": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal",
      "ios": {
        "simulator": true
      },
      "channel": "development-simulator"
    },
    "preview": {
      "distribution": "internal",
      "channel": "preview"
    },
    "production": {
      "channel": "production"
    }
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {}
  }
}
```

I've tried going to older builds - but I didn't change anything in the following files that should impact it, just components.

I've tried clearly my caches and reinstalling with these commands

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
npm cache clean --force
watchman watch-del-all
rm -rf node_modules/.cache/babel-loader
rm -rf node_modules/.cache/webpack
rm -rf node_modules
npx expo install
npx expo prebuild
```